# Passing data into a routed component with Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that's loaded via routing and I'm trying to pass data into the component from a parent component.  How would I go about doing this?

**Parent Component Class**

```
export class HomeComponent{
    userName: string;
    userId: string;

    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.userName = "user name";
        this.userId = "user id";
    }
}
```

**Parent Component Template**

```
<div>
    <p>Parent Component</p>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Child Component Class**

```
export class ChildComponent{
    userName: string;
    userId: string;
}
```

Basically, the home component has child routes that are only available to that component.  The child component is automatically loaded along with the parent component, but I want to use the data from the parent component, inside the child component.  For practicality purposes and not having questions about whether my application is set up correctly, it is.

Comment: Provide a service at the parent component, inject it in the child component. Ideally use one or more Observables (BehaviorSubject) in the service to pass the values along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables via the Router if you want to, eg.

```
const routes = 
[                                                                                     
    { path: "child/:customerId", component: ChildComponent },                                                               
]
```

Then you can access `customerId` via the ActivatedRouteSnapshot

eg.

```
class ChildComponent
{
  constructor(route : ActivatedRouteSnapshot)
  {
    const customerId = +route.params["customerId"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing a service with reactive data is the best solution.